# View files on PC from iphone backup without itunes?

Tags: iphone

I need to view files from an old backup that i put a password on but cant for the life of remember the password. Is there anyway i can view these files on PC? I need text msgs and emails that where on the phone at time of backup.

Comment: I would really hope that something protected by a password can't be broken otherwise there is little point in having one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create backup iPhone with forgotten encryption password](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86173/create-backup-iphone-with-forgotten-encryption-password)

Comment: This is a duplicate of my question above, and no, you cannot do this.

Comment: @Robuust your "duplicate" question was asked after this one. I'll see if I can dupe both to something from several years ago. We should have plenty of similar questions on the site to clean up a bit but even if the same answer explaining where and how iTunes makes backups might address both questions, they don't seem to be perfect duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [TotalSaver Encrypted Recovery Service](http://www.myphonedata.com/encryptedrecovery) from MyPhoneData

Comment: From the requirements for that application: "An unencrypted backup of your iPhone 2G, iPhone 3G, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S or iPhone 5 running on iOS4, iOS5 or iOS6, created by the iTunes software"  In this instance, the user only has an encrypted backup.

Comment: sorry, I pointed to the software that I had used. I didn't exactly remember the link to their encrypted one. It specifies that one has to know the password. Its actually Total Saver encrypted service - http://www.myphonedata.com/encryptedrecovery